# Facebook SDK logout not working

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook PHP-SDK to sign in users and it works fine. I'm having a problem logging users out correctly. After clicking the logout button and then clicking the sign in button it does not redirect the user to Facebook's sign in page, instead it logs them into my site as if the logout wasn't successful. Here is my code to sign in a user:

```
function authenticate_user()
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
    $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
    $CI->load->library('facebook', $config);

    $user = $CI->facebook->getUser();

    if ($user)
    {
        try
        {
            $user_profile = $CI->facebook->api('/me');
            return $user_profile;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e)
        {
            error_log($e);
        }
    }

    return FALSE;

}

public function signin()
{
    $user_profile = authenticate_user();
    if (!$user_profile)
    {   
        $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
        redirect($loginUrl);
    }

    $this->load->model("user_model");

    if ($userRow = $this->user_model->user_exists($user_profile["id"]))
    {
        set_session($user_profile, $userRow->privileges);
        redirect("member_controller/members");
    }
}
```

#### This is my logout code:

```
public function fb_signout()
{
    $params = array( 'next' => 'http://www.' + $host + '/index.php/authentication_controller/signout');
    redirect($this->facebook->getLogoutUrl($params)); // $params is optional.
}

public function signout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect("http://www." + $host + "/");
}
```

#### UPDATE:

The SDK was using native PHP sessions and calling `$this->session->sess_destroy()` would not destroy it, I needed to include `session_destroy()` in my signout function.

Comment: Check if the api you're using doesn't set another cookie or session with auth information ...

Comment: Yep, you might have some javascript (from the Facebook Javascript SDK) that is reconnecting the user (either by a true set on the FB.init's status or by a FB.getLoginStatus() call)

Comment: It looks like the logout link in the example source that came with Facebook's SDK doesn't work either.  I'm assuming it's an issue with the SDK itself, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The facebook SDK uses native PHP sessions but codeigniter doesn't. what you want to do is add `session_destroy();` in your signout method to kill PHP native session.

Hope that helps!